# Postgresql IN clause versus nested SELECT with JOIN performance

Tags: postgresql, join, count

I have a query right now that works well but will have scaling problems. The solution I have found is wildly slow. I'm looking to speed up the second query.

Old query that won't scale well:

```
SELECT user.score
FROM users
WHERE
  user.id IN (
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM companies_users 
    ON companies_users.company_id = X
)
```

Then I would iterate across the different scores to group them. Scores range from -10 to 10. The problem comes from the IN SELECT statement and the iteration. There could be over a million user_ids returned.

The alternative I've come up with should scale better but is wildly slow:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total_scores,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
    JOIN companies_users as cu ON cu.company_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE users.score = 10 AND cu.company_id = X) as "10",
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
    JOIN companies_users as cu ON cu.company_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE users.score = 9 AND cu.company_id = X) as "9",
...
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
    JOIN companies_users as cu ON cu.company_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE users.score = -9 AND cu.company_id = X) as "-9",
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
    JOIN companies_users as cu ON cu.company_id = cu.user_id
    WHERE users.score = -10 AND cu.company_id = X) as "-10"
FROM users
  JOIN companies_users as cu ON cu.company_id = cu.user_id
  WHERE cu.company_id = X
```

The first query requires iteration to get into working data. The second is good to go.

Is there a way to pull the JOIN out of the nested SELECTs? That seems to be causing the majority of the slowdown in the second query. Also, am I right that the first query won't scale well when dealing with millions of ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be the problem with:

```
SELECT u.score
FROM companies_users cu
    JOIN users u ON cu.user_id = u.id
WHERE cu.company_id=?
GROUP BY u.score
ORDER BY u.score
```

?

Also, do you have appropriate indices? You need an index on `companies_users(company_id)`, and one on `users(id)`. You may try adding one on companies_users(user_id) just in case the planner decides it's better to do the query the the other way around. `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` are your friends.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That is pretty close to perfect. I'm actually looking for the counts on the different scores. I used your solution but changed the select portion to u.score, count(u.score) and have got all the data! Thanks again.